# Header above a YUI MenuBar, without scrolling issue?

Tags: scroll, yui, menubar

The YUI MenuBar seems to have an issue with being below a header.

HTML:

```
<body class="yui-skin-sam">
    <a id="headerStyle"><img href="/" src="/images/Header.jpg" alt="Home"/></a>
    <div id="menuPanel" style="padding:1px">
```

CSS:

```
#headerStyle {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var oMenu = new YAHOO.widget.MenuBar("mymenu");
oMenu.addItems([
    {
        text: "Main",
        submenu: {
            id: "menu1",
            itemdata: [
               { text: "1" },
               { text: "2" },
               { text: "3" },
               { text: "4" },
               { text: "5" },
               { text: "6" },
               { text: "7" },
               { text: "8" }
    ]
        }
    }
]);
oMenu.render($("#menuPanel").get(0));
oMenu.show();
```

Clicking MenuBar for the first time, it displays only 3 items with scrolling.
The issue goes away after the first click.

Any ideas?

Comment: This still isn't enough code to reproduce your problems.  On FireFox, I cannot get the scrollbar to appear when attaching it to #menuPanel, even after an image.  An example page of your code would be best to see what is going on.

Comment: Hmm, I fixed it. Setting the Height in the css header seems to cause the issue. Sorry I can't readily post an example page.
Thank you for you're help.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the height property in the CSS file seems to cause this issue.
Simple removing it makes it function as it should.